# WebAssembly calling JavaScript methods from wasm i.e. within C++ code

Tags: javascript, c++11, emscripten, webassembly

I was playing with WebAssembly and so far and I was able to manage emscripten compile my test C++ project to wasm file
em++ provides me 2 files i.e.

mainTest.js  mainTest.wasm

When I load mainTest.js in my html page then I get a JavaScript object called 
"**Module**".

I did found how to call C++/wasm methods from javascript i.e. something like:

```
var myTestInteger = Module._callMyTestMethod();
```

and read strings from the 
**Module.wasmMemory.buffer**
, but I do NOT understand how to call JavaScript from C++ code.

i.e. I would like to be able to do something like that:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern void testExternJSMethod();

int main() 
{
    cout << " Hello From my Test1 !" << endl;

    testExternJSMethod();
    return 0;
}
int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE callMyTestMethod(){
    return 26;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and the my js method testExternMethod that I am loading in another js file called utils.js

```
function testExternMethod() {
  console.log("Hello from testExternMethod!" + )
}
```

Here I would like to call the JavaScript testExternJSMethod from C++.

When I run the page in Firefox get "-1" in the debugger console.

So what I am missing in this case? Unfortunately The Mozilla documentation is giving only examples in those S-expressions instead of C++.

What am I missing in example? In C++ I have defined the method with the extern keyword i.e.

```
extern void testExternJSMethod();
```

but I get the feeling that that is not all I have to do.

I believe that I should somehow link that JavaScript method to the Module somehow but I do not know how. 
**Module.asm** gives me the **exports**. Which method call should give me the **imports**? since I believe that this `_testExternJSMethod()` should be in some imports method I can not figure out how to get to it.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not exactly sure of your use case, but you are missing important steps to be able to use your function `testExternalJSMethod`. You have two options here:

## Option 1 - Library

1 - Define your function in c/c++ .

```
extern void testExternalJSMethod();
```

2 - Create a file called `myLibrary.js`

3 - The JS function needs to be added to the `LibraryManager` in your library file with the following code:

```
function makeAlert(text) {
    alert(text);
}

if (typeof mergeInto !== 'undefined') mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    testExternalJSMethod: function() {
        makeAlert("Hello world");
    }
});
```

4 - If `testExternalJSMethod` depends on anything outside of its own scope (for example, `makeAlert` above), make sure to include the script in your html page

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="myLibrary.js"></script>
```

5 - Add option `--js-library` to your emcc command, and immediately after the relative path to `myLibrary.js`

```
emcc ... --js-library myLibrary.js
```

## Option 2 - Passing Pointers

1 - Define your javascript function type in c/c++

```
typedef void testExternalJSMethod()
```

2 - Wherever you want this function to be used, accept an int param which will be the function pointer, and cast the pointer to your function

```
void passFnPointer(int ptr) {
    ((testExternalJSMethod*)ptr)();
}
```

3 - Use emscripten's `addFunction()` and store its returned value (the pointer in c/c++)

```
var fnPtr = Module.addFunction(function () {
    alert("You called testExternalJSMethod");
});
```

4 - Use the stored pointer value from step 3 to pass to our function `passFnPointer`

```
var passFnPointer = Module.cwrap('passFnPointer', 'undefined', ['number']);
passFnPointer(fnPtr);
```

5 - Add option `-s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS` to your emcc command

```
emcc ... -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=10
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried looking at the Emscripten documentation? It has a whole section on [interacting with code](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html) that details how to expose C / C++ functions to JavaScript and call JavaScript functions from C / C++.

> Emscripten provides two main approaches for calling JavaScript from C/C++: running the script using emscripten_run_script() or writing “inline JavaScript”.

It is worth noting that the Mozilla documentation details plain WebAssembly, whereas Emscripten adds a lot more framework and tooling around WebAssembly in order to make it easier to port large C / C++ codebases.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did found the page you are referring to one hour after i posted this question. emscripten_run_script() does work. But what i was specifically looking for to make that example work with a function poiter thus i can pass values back and fort. Unfortunately i can not find a full example of that, and i still have not found my mistake.

Comment: I'm researching this very topic, & am trying to establish if the "inline Javascript" method can call existing Javascript functions, & not merely the code embedded in the call.